# I having issues with this program. Anyone seeing what I am doing wrong? Fairly new to this

Tags: c++, if-statement

Cannot get this run right. I having issues with this program. Anyone seeing what I am doing wrong? Fairly new to this. I have trying all day to get this right. and I am frustrated to no end right now. If anyone sees what I am doing wrong I would really appreciate it.

```
main ()
    {
    int adultTickets = 0, seniorTickets = 0, childTickets = 0, infantTickets = 0, baggage = 0, age = 0, passengerTotal = 0;
    double totalBaggagefee = 0.0, baggageFee1 = 20.00, baggageFee2 = 35.00, adultFee = 147.30, seniorFee = 137.75, childFee = 110.25, infantFee = 0.0, totalTicket = 0.0, totalwithCheckedbaggage = 0.0;
    char reply;
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    string Yes = "YES";
    string No = "NO";
    string quit = "QUIT";

    cout << "Enter your age. ";
    cin >> age;
    if (age > 18);
    {
        cout << "You are old enough to buy a ticket." << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to purchase a ticket now? ";
        cin >> reply;

            if (input == Yes);
            {
                cout << "How many Adult Tickets? "; 
                cin >> adultTickets;
                cout << "How many Senior Tickets? "; 
                cin >> seniorTickets;
                cout << "How many Child Tickets? "; 
                cin >> childTickets;
                cout << "How many Infant Tickets? "; 
                cin >> infantTickets;
                cout << "Number of checked baggage? "; 
                cin >> baggage;
                cout << endl;

                    if (baggage <= passengerTotal);
                        totalBaggagefee = passengerTotal*baggageFee1;
                        totalTicket = (adultTickets*adultFee)+(seniorTickets*seniorFee)+(childTickets*childFee)+(infantTickets*infantFee);
                        totalwithCheckedbaggage = totalTicket+totalBaggagefee;
                    {    
                        cout << "Your total including check baggage is " << totalwithCheckedbaggage << "" << endl;
                    }    
                    else (baggage >= passengerTotal);
                        totalBaggagefee = passengerTotal * baggageFee1 + 1 * baggageFee2;
                        totalTicket = (adultTickets*adultFee)+(seniorTickets*seniorFee)+(childTickets*childFee)+(infantTickets*infantFee);
                        totalwithCheckedbaggage = totalTicket+totalBaggagefee;
                    {    
                        cout << "Your total including check baggage is " << totalwithCheckedbaggage << "" << endl;
                    }
            else (input == No);
            {
                cout << "You are a minor, have an adult purchase your ticket. ";
                cout << "Thank you." << endl;
            }    
                cout << "Type quit to end. ";
                cin >> reply;
                cout << endl;
                exit(1);
    }            
    else if (age<18);
    {
        cout << "You are too young, have an adult buy your ticket. " << endl;
    }

            return 0;

            }}
```

Comment: Ugh something happened in transferring it to the question

Comment: Try just copy-pasting the whole code at once as an [**edit to your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50092291/edit). Don't add your own backticks or spaces -- simply highlight all of your code and press `CTRL` + `K` to indent it :)

Comment: Careful with the indentation on this code. Indentation conveys both intent and meaning, so mistakes in indentation often signify bugs. As a note, if you want to wrangle this code into a form that's easier to deal with, think about writing a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), something that's simpler than it sounds. What you'd do then is have a loop that prints the state's prompt, awaits input, runs a state-specific function to test that input, and potentially transitions to another state. That avoids a lot of the nesting you've got going on here.

Comment: Part of this assignment is nesting. So I assume I am doing what she is asking me for, but I am guessing the if-else statements are not in appropriate spots.

Comment: So I have fixed most of the program, the only issue I am running across now is that instead of prompting the question first it needs me to enter aomething to kick start the program. Any Ideas?

Comment: Look at the 5th line of your program, `cin >> input;`

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much. Got it

Comment: *"Cannot get this run right. I having issues with this program."* are awful problem statements. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is that you put semicolons ";" after the if, else and else if-statements. Remove them.

You can write an if-else-statement with or without curly braces. If you write it without brackets, only the first code part until the next semicolon gets executed if the if-statement evaluates to true. If you are using curly brackets, you can define a whole punch of statements within that curly brackets block. Code lines inside that block get executed when the expression inside the if-statement evaluates to true.

Take the following if-statement for example:

```
int age = 22;
if(age > 18) cout << "Hello World" << endl;
{
cout << "Inside block" << endl;
}
```

In this case "Inside block" gets printed everytime. Even if age is less or equals 18. The string "Hello World" only gets printed when age is greater then 18.

So if you put a semicolon after an if-else-statement, basically nothing happens because it's a perfectly valid statement that does nothing.

Let's take the first if-statement for example. Instead of:

```
if(age > 18);
{
```

you write:

```
if(age > 18) {
```

Whenever you are declaring a block with curly brackets, you normally don't need a semicolon before or after the block.

Comment: That does not seem to fix my problem. I am getting errors on line 46 and 53 saying that there needs to be and else with the if. How do I fix it so they are nested correctly?

Comment: Change the else(input == No); to else { and the else (baggage >= passengerTotal); to else {. Else-statements don't take expressions.

Comment: You also have to replace "if (baggage <= passengerTotal); totalBaggagefee = passengerTotal*baggageFee1; totalTicket = (adultTickets*adultFee)+(seniorTickets*seniorFee)+(childTickets*childFee)+(infantTickets*infantFee); totalwithCheckedbaggage = totalTicket+totalBaggagefee; { " with "if (baggage <= passengerTotal) { totalBaggagefee = passengerTotal*baggageFee1; totalTicket = (adultTickets*adultFee)+(seniorTickets*seniorFee)+(childTickets*childFee)+(infantTickets*infantFee); totalwithCheckedbaggage = totalTicket+totalBaggagefee; ".

Comment: And the if(input == Yes) is missing a closing bracket. So put a &quot;}&quot; before the second else-statement. Then you have to delete the last curly bracket after the return 0;.

Comment: Oh, I&amp;#39;ve found another thing. Your main function does not have a return type. So instead of writing &amp;quot;main() {&amp;quot; you write &amp;quot;int main() {&amp;quot;. Every function needs a return type (except for constructors). If a function does not need one, you still have to write "void".

Answer (score 1):

Your problems are with `if` and `if-else` syntax.

In C++ an `if()` condition controls the next statement and only the next statement.
Just to keep you on your toes 'next statement' can be empty.

So `if(input == YES);` means "if input is `"YES"`, do nothing special and carry on".
An `if` followed by an empty statement isn't massively useful, but the syntax admits it.

If you want `if()` to control multiple statements then you introduce a block (which acts like a single statement in this respect).
Blocks are collections of statements surrounded by `{` and `}`

```
if (baggage <= passengerTotal);
    totalBaggagefee = passengerTotal*baggageFee1;
    totalTicket = (adultTickets*adultFee)+/*...*/;
    totalwithCheckedbaggage =totalTicket+totalBaggagefee;
{    
    cout << "Your total including check baggage is " << 
       totalwithCheckedbaggage << "" << endl;


}    
else (baggage >= passengerTotal);
```

Should be:

```
if (baggage <= passengerTotal){//<---- Start block following condition!
    totalBaggagefee = passengerTotal*baggageFee1;
    totalTicket = (adultTickets*adultFee)+/*...*/;
    totalwithCheckedbaggage =totalTicket+totalBaggagefee;
    cout << "Your total including check baggage is " << 
       totalwithCheckedbaggage << "" << endl;

} else if (baggage >= passengerTotal)
```

Notice I've replaced some code with `/*...*/` to make it fit the screen nicely.

Also notice I've changed the `else` clause. 
Before the else didn't match up with the `if` because the `if` finished several statements ago (due to the error with `if() ;`).

But the second problem was `else (baggage>=passengerTotal);` also does nothing.
In C++ you can just use an expression as a statement. That code will check the condition and ignore the result! Welcome to C++.

`else` isn't an implicit `else-if` so you have to explicitly make the `else` clause an `if` statement using `else if`.

There appear to be a number of similar errors but I'll leave it to you to tidy up fully.

On a style note, I recommend only using

```
if(){
}
```

or

```
if(){
} else {
}
```

And if you like

```
if(){
}else if (){
}
```

These can be composed into chains if necessary:

```
if(){
}else if (){
}else {
}
```

That is *always* follow `if()` with a statement block and ignore that if it's a single statement you don't need the `{ }`. I tends to make things easier to read.

Why are things like `if(flag==true);` valid? Probably historical reasons inherited from the C syntax which was kept simple on the tiny machines it was designed on. `if(flag==true);` is the same as `(flag==true);` and unless there are side-effects (possible but very unwise) both do nothing.

If you ever do want to introduce an empty statement or block, I recommend a comment.

```
if(condition){
   /* Does nothing.*/
}
```

That's not much use in an if-statement but you do see constructs like:

```
while(do_a_thing()){
    /*Do nothing*/
}
```

If `do_a_thing()` returns `false` if there's nothing left to do.